# How do I use tabHost for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tabhost

I have looked at posts on Stack Overflow and at tutorials on other websites, and I cannot understand how to use `TabHost`.  Can someone please explain it to me and maybe send me a link to a tutorial?

Comment: is there really a realtionship between tabHosts vs. fragments?

Comment: @AndyHarris TabHost is NOT deprecated. TabActivity is. Please stop spreading false rumors.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[image: Concept TabHost]

[image]

1. In ManiActivity extends TabActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(new Intent(this  ,FirstActivity.class )));
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(new Intent(this , SecondActivity.class )));
       mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


   }
   }
   ```

> - In this activity not use layout "activity_main.xml" .
> - Tabhost mTabHost = getTabHost(); is create main tab.
> - mTabHost.newTabSpec("first") is create tabspec id "first".
> - setIndicator("First") is create text "First" in title tab.
> - setContent(new Intent(this  ,FirstActivity.class )) is use content from FirstActivity.class ( FirstActivity.java )
> - mTabHost.addTab(....) is add spectab to main tab
> - mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0) is defult tab when start page.

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView( R.layout.first_layout );
}

}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView( R.layout.second_layout );
}
}
```

> - "R.layout.first_layout" is content from first_layout.xml
> - "R.layout.second_layout" is content from second_layout.xml

In AndroidManifest.xml add activity name ".FirstActivity" and ".SecondActivity" in example xml.

[image]

Finish!!!!!

[image]

Comment: The tabs dont appear... why?

Comment: getTabHost() does not work for me. It does not import as a resource.

Comment: @Eenvincible you should have your activity Extend TabActivity

Comment: Shouldn't we use fragment for each tabs ?

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND yes `Fragment`'s are always the better choice

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 7):

First of all while `TabHost` is not deprecated, `TabActivity` on other hand is deprecated due to `Fragment` API.

There are two ways to use TabHost; using Fragment via `FragmentTabHost` and using `TabHost.TabContentFactory`.

**1. Using Fragment via `FragmentTabHost`**

This sample code show you how to use TabHost in Activity.

**FragmentTabHostActivity.java**

```
public class FragmentTabHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tab_host_activity);

        FragmentTabHost fragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        fragmentTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
        fragmentTabHost.addTab(getTabSpec1(fragmentTabHost), Tab1Fragment.class, null);
        fragmentTabHost.addTab(getTabSpec2(fragmentTabHost), Tab2Fragment.class, null);
    }

    private TabHost.TabSpec getTabSpec1(FragmentTabHost tabHost) {
        return tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab")
            .setIndicator("Tab1");
    }

    private TabHost.TabSpec getTabSpec2(FragmentTabHost tabHost) {
        return tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab")
            .setIndicator("Tab 2");
    }
}
```

**fragment_tab_host_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Actually by using Fragment, you can use Tab inside a Fragment ([Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)).

**2. Using `TabHost.ContentFactory`**

**TabHostActivity.java**

```
public class TabHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        tabHost.addTab(getTabSpec1(tabHost));
        tabHost.addTab(getTabSpec2(tabHost));
    }

    private TabHost.TabSpec getTabSpec1(TabHost tabHost) {
        return tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab")
            .setIndicator("Tab1")
            .setContent(this);
    }

    private TabHost.TabSpec getTabSpec2(TabHost tabHost) {
        return tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab")
            .setIndicator("Tab 2")
            .setContent(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, null);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

However, I personally recommend using newest [Material Design style `TabLayout` class](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).