# Alternative of TabAcitivity

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

Hi Friends i want to create tab's in project. For making tab there is two way which i found

1) Extends the activity class with TabActivity class which is deprecated as i seem this is a easy way but don't why it is deprecated so i want to know whether any other class or any alternative for that class.

2) Create individual activity for every tab which lengthy but convenient way but still feels TabActivity is fast one.

I was wondering if anybody could tell me,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For making tab there is two way which i found

You can also:

- Use a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, such as `PagerTabStrip`, the `TabPagerIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator project, `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, etc.
- Use tabs in the action bar (note: these will convert into a drop-down list in some device sizes and orientations)
- Use `FragmentTabHost`
- Use `TabHost` and `TabWidget` in a regular `Activity`

The following sample projects demonstrate:

- `PagerTabStrip`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/TabPager
- `TabPageIndicator`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/VPI
- action bar tabs: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/TabFragmentDemo
- `TabHost` and `TabWidget`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab

Note that the first three samples all use ActionBarSherlock, so they run on Android 2.x devices. The fourth one should run on anything from Android 1.0 onwards.

Comment: i'll tried FragmentTabHost but it is not supported in mostly previous android version.
Do you have any link or more information regarding FragmentTabHost.

Comment: @LoveGarg: `FragmentTabHost` is part of the Android Support package and should work back to API Level 4: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: But in development we give minimum require sdk we give android 2.2 which is not supported by it is there any working way to use it in below version also.
And thanks for your quick reply!!!!

Comment: @LoveGarg: "which is not supported by it is" -- the SupportV4Demos project, from Google, shows a few samples of `FragmentTabHost`, and their project has an `android:minSdkVersion` of `4`: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/Support4Demos

Answer (score 2):

use [Fragments](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html&ei=V8bOUZC_MczqrQeu3YGoAQ&usg=AFQjCNH1lOgCRgUnGZWyz29o5Kns4ZWBBw&sig2=_KTuzn2AxNVgM-SqdGgUeA&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bmk&cad=rja) as an alternative of TabActivity . To get a feel like Tabs you can do this. Use a [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). Add different Fragments in it. And use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to switch between different fragments.

Comment: Hi Stine can you give me any working example of FragmentActivity
 And Thanks for your response