# fixed tab view to display 3-4 screens in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want a tab view activity which will display 3-4 screens in it. I don't care if tabs are fixed or can swipe but I want it to support atleast API 8 or min. a rough overview you can get by below image.
[image: sample of requirement]

Please let me know what should I use and is there any build-in API or something that can help.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Sourabh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative of TabAcitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379725/alternative-of-tabacitivity)

Answer (score 1):

Navigating using tabs is easily implemented using `TabHost`. There is one main `Activity` which lists all the tabhosts, and they define the other screens. This is explained very well in this tutorial. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

The code for each screen is written on a seperate `Activity`.

Hope this answers your question.