# Tabs - Without using TabHost

Tags: android

I want to develop tabs like the attached image. But, do not want to use Tabhost for this.Any help is highly Appreciated.[image]

Below is the XML am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#0C3666"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NEWS"
        android:textColor="@color/main_white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quotes_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="QUOTES"
        android:textColor="@color/main_white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editor_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/main_white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="ST"
        android:textColor="@color/main_white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Above is the layout. I want to know how i can draw the separtor line "|" between tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505236/how-to-implement-android-tab-menu-without-deprecated-tabhost)

Comment: Thanks, but the link you have provided is not helpful.

Comment: Use action bar  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html  and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html may be helpful for you

Comment: then give some more detail like where do u want to show it , else action bar can be used for general cases

Comment: Did you at least tried something? You could use Buttons, TextViews custom views etc...

Comment: am using four TextViews in horizontal linear layout. Now, am able to set the selected and unselected state also for the tabs. One issue am facing now is in drawing the separator "|" between tabs. How can i achieve this.

Comment: For that vertical line you could use a simple `View` class(placed between the `TextViews` with a small width) for which you'll set the background to color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add the ImageView with bar as background of  image where you want bar

Comment: is it possible to do this without image

Comment: @user694688 can use any view or linear layout add background color to it