# Fragment tab host error:Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have been using the fragment tab host for some time and it was working fine.
Suddenly i am getting this layout compilation error.

```
Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null
```

activity_tabhost_search.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Please don't close it as duplicate as I checked all threads but I was not able to solve this.

Comment: I opened a bug-report, please vote on it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78772

Answer (score 0):

As I think you have to surround the `LinearLayout` with `TabHost`

Maybe also this helps you [How do I use tabHost for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622539/how-do-i-use-tabhost-for-android)

The Vogella Tab Tutorial as linked in the other topic, works great and I'm using it in my app at the moment.

Comment: Threre is a java code http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabsFragment.html but i could not find the layout where I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TabWinget android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

should be changed to:

```
 <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```